# How to create custom layouts in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I need to create several custom layout based on random combinations. So according to the bootstrap's 12 column concept, i am little bit confused will it working or not. So i need some practical ideas for achieving this. For example, please take a look at the below example.
[image]

or

[image]

or

[image]

The layout will be dynamic. From the server i will get start coordinate, height and width of each block .Please let me know if need any further inputs.

Comment: For a start, you need to at least try something first, this is not a code writing service. Secondly, you need to think mobile-first, that's the point of Bootstrap.

Comment: Here is some advice. Left 4 squares is one column. The big square with the two under it are another column. Then under the big square, thats two columns. Pretty simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create pretty much ANY custom layout with Bootstrap. This is accomplished by [nesting rows and columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#nesting) inside other rows and columns.

Here's how you can create the layout for the above example:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3"></div>
        <div class="col"></div>
        <div class="col"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

NOTE:

`col` is the default i.e. non-responsive class. In other words, it's the class for the smallest screen size and that means that without adding any additional responsive classes, the layout will look the same for all screen sizes. To make it responsive you need to add the desired responsive classes.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't mean for a single layout. From the server i will get start coordinate and height and width of each block

Comment: Based on your comment: You don't seem to understand how Bootstrap works and what "responsive" means in general. So, you might want to start reading about the basics of Bootstrap and Bootstrap layout first.

Comment: @KIRANKJ You seem to want to build websites the way we used to build websites in 2001 using tables. That's not how web development is done today. It's completely different from what it used to be 20 years ago.

Comment: My requirement is little complex. So i asked this kind of question. At last i realize that i have to iterate through my layout and create an algorithm based on that. After that i have to implement through the bootsrtap. I'm sorry.

Comment: I don't think the issue is the "complexity". Rather, the examples/images you posted indicate that you don't understand how Bootstrap works on a basic level. For example, the height of a column is determined by the content inside it. So, the first 2 of your images can represent identical Bootstrap layout because of that.